# Printing a char array

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

I am wondering what is wrong with my code. I normally use scanf but am trying get the hang of fgets. But when I try to print a char array where each element of the array is on a separate line, but even though I defined the limit of the array as an arbitrarily high number, it only has a limit of eleven lines. I am a beginner programmer so try to be as simple as you can.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define max_line 4096
int main(void) {
    char str[max_line];
    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(str, max_line, stdin);
    for (int i=0;i <max_line && i!='\n'; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am wanting to get a result like this.

```
Enter string: Hello 
H
e
l
l
o
```

But it turns out quite differently

```
Enter string: Hello 
H
e
l
l
o 
/n //Sorry, I don't know how to add new lines in stackoverflow, but I think you get the idea.
/n
/n
/n
/n
```

Comment: `i!='\n'` --> `str[i]!='\n'`

Comment: So in my condition, I just change it right?

Comment: Why `i!='\n'`? Comeon, think twice! ;-) You want to test exactly *what* to not be a new-line?

Comment: Sorry @alk, I've been coding for the past few days with little sleep, so common sense just flew over my head. Thanks for the helps, guys.

Comment: "*little sleep*", not a good thing.

Comment: `i!='\n'` meant `i!=10` in your system. `i <4096 && i!=10` is `i < 10`

Comment: Not much choice, had a few essays coming up and didn't want to leave it until the last second so decided to pull a few all-nighters, so I could get the drafts out of the way.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, I'm pretty new to programming so could you please explain why '\n' = 10 if you have time that is

Comment: See `LF` of  [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check that `str[i]` is **NOT EQUAL** to `'\n'` instead of checking `i!='\n'`. 
As @BLUEPIXY pointed out it means i != 10, being '\n' equal to 10 in the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code.

So change the condition to:

```
for (int i=0;i <max_line && str[i]!='\n'; i++) {
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
int main(void) {
    int i;
    char str[max_line];
    memset(str, 0x0, max_line);
    printf("Enter string: ");
    fgets(str, max_line, stdin);
    for (i=0;i < strlen(str) ; i++) {
        printf("\n%c", str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At the end (after Hello), null char not there, hence the junk output.

Comment: Please see the comments to the the OP.